# Is there a way to cancel a beam attack on iPad?

Tags: ios, ftl-faster-than-light

When playing on the tablet, once you start drawing the path of the beam to perform an attack, when the beam is already charged and ready, is there a way to cancel the attack?

The game auto-pauses while selecting the position of the beam, but sometimes you realize that there is something that you want to do first so you need to stop that attack. However when you raise your fingers from the screen, the action resumes automatically giving you no option to pause or cancel the beam attack.

Comment: Just think of it [like chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch-move_rule)...

Comment: Is drawing an impossible path for the beam a way to cancel it ? I don't play the game so I can't tell but that's what i would try

Comment: @WizLiz I tried and didn't worked

Comment: What happens if you put more fingers on the screen?

Comment: On the PC version, you can cancel it by selecting it again, or selecting a different weapon. Can you do that with iOS?

Comment: @Brilliand it only detects the first two fingers

Comment: @SysDragon Does aiming a beam require two fingers?  I'm wondering if the second finger provides a way to cancel (i.e. "No, I was actually trying to zoom out, not aim.").

Comment: @Brilliand One finger changes the direction of the beam, two fingers changes the position around.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit awkward with your hands but what i do is turn my ipad to standby or press the home button this will cancel the action!

Comment: I don't understand the picture... is this related to the question or answer?

Comment: Not in Particular